# Can member of java class may not have fully qualified name except anonymous class?

Tags: java, class

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7 specifies that

> Each member class, member interface, and array type *may* have a fully
>   qualified name:
>
> A member class or member interface M of another class or interface C
>   has a fully qualified name if and only if C has a fully qualified
>   name.
>        In that case, the fully qualified name of M consists of the fully qualified name of C, followed by ".", followed by the simple name of
>   M.

But according to the same doc, every class or interface have FQN.

> Every primitive type, named package, top level class, and top level
>   interface has a fully qualified name

Since *may* is empathized in this doc, then what is the example of member without qualified name according to this doc except anonymous classes? If only anonymous classes are the case, then why *may* is specified in such general way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But according to the same doc, every class or interface have FQN.*

Nope: [the docs you quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) say (emphasis mine):

> Every primitive type, named package, **top level** class, and **top level** interface has a fully qualified name

Of member classes, member interfaces and array types, they say this (emphasis mine):

> - A member class or member interface M of another class or interface C has a fully qualified name if and **only if** C has a fully qualified name.
> - An array type has a fully qualified name if and **only if** its element type has a fully qualified name.

And (emphasis still mine):

> A **local class** or anonymous class does not have a fully qualified name.

So not only anonymous classes, but also some member classes, member interfaces and array types might have no fully-qualified name, and local classes never do. Here's a demonstration of some examples:

```java
class Outer {
    // anonymous class has no FQN
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        // member class has no FQN, because its enclosing class has no FQN
        class Member {}

        public void run() {
            // array type has no FQN, because its element type has no FQN
            Member[] members = new Member[3];

            // local class has no FQN
            class Local {}
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A local class or anonymous class does not have a fully qualified name.

So rules out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class MyLocal{}
}
```

> An array type has a fully qualified name if and only if its element
>   type has a fully qualified name.

So rules out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class MyLocal{}      // doesn't have
    MyLocal[] arr = {};  // nor this one
}
```

> A member class or member interface M of another class or interface C
>   has a fully qualified name if and only if C has a fully qualified
>   name.

So rules out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class MyLocal{}
    class MyLocalChild extends MyLocal {}
}
```

Comment: @kaya3 Is this what he is getting at? If not, I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Your examples for the local class and the array type are both correct; but "member type" is not about inheritance. `MyLocalChild` is not a member class, although it does have no FQN due to being a local class.